# opencv save file xml

Tags: c, xml, opencv

I hope that you can help me...

I have an IplImage (reimg_right) 320 X 240, IPL_DEPTH_32F
and I want to save it as an image and as an xml file.
I use this code:

```
sprintf(name1,"path1/image.bmp");
sprintf(name2,"path2/feature_image32F.xml");
cvSaveImage(name1,reimg_right);
cvSave(name2, reimg_right, NULL, NULL, cvAttrList(0,0));
```

all is ok but the problem is that in the xml file I don't have a matrix 320 X 240 but a matrix 19200 X 4 !!!
someone knows how to hold the dimensions? 
thanks gabriele

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what OpenCV version you are using, but some time ago you could do just:

```
cvSave("file.xml", my_img);
```

assuming **my_img** as:

```
CvMat* my_img = cvCreateMat(320, 240, CV_32FC1);
```

But since you are using an IplImage, you could convert them like:

```
CvMat mat;
CvMat* my_img = cvGetMat(reimg_right, &mat);
cvSave("file.xml", my_img);
```

Comment: You should check this reference when using CvMat:  http://note.sonots.com/OpenCV/MatrixOperations.html#qcb4d539

Comment: I have not found anything concerning saving matrices at  http://note.sonots.com/OpenCV/MatrixOperations.html#qcb4d539 . Have I missed something?